# jquery create keypress event

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

We developed a firefox plugin to fill a form with some data from an external source. The plugin has a keyboard shortcut "ALT+SHIFT+L"

What we wanna do is, put a button to the page and create a keypress event on button's click event. So when we click the button, our plugin should fill the form.

How can we do this work with jquery.

p.s. our plugin already has a button to fill the form, but it stays in the navigation bar of firefox. We are using r-kiosk plugin to use firefox full screen, such as a kiosk app. So we need to put a button into our page to trigger keypress.

Thx. anyone who helps.

Comment: Well, hard to tell if you don't post any code.

Comment: what do you mean any code? i'm not asking help for a particular code piece. i m just asking a way about doing an event. So what kind of code piece do you want me to post?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to trigger a Keydown event on button click, you can use this.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
   var e = $.Event("keydown");
   e.which = 108; // # key code for l
   e.altKey = true;
   e.shiftKey = true;
   $(document).trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: Do onething. write one function like follows. $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { }); check this function gets called when you call $(document).trigger(e);